# Legacy GCE and GKE metadata server endpoints and Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I received an email from Google saying that some of my Cloud Functions are still calling the pre-GA v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints of the App Engine and Cloud Functions metadata server. The email suggests that I may be using old Google client libraries that are making the requests.

I upgraded firebase-admin, firebase-functions and firebase-tools, and I still needed to upgrade my functions to use Node 10 so I did that. I redeployed my apps and they appear to be working.

Now, how can I check that I have solved the legacy endpoint problem?

Comment: Could you please share which are the endpoints you are targetting to?

Comment: @JoséSoní I don't know! In their email, Google says that if we are not making direct requests to the endpoints (I am not), it must be out-of-date client libraries making the requests. So I updated the libraries that could be responsible and all should be well.

The apps in question are not yet released but If these functions were used in production, I would want to be able to check that they will continue to work after the 30 September shutdown.

Comment: which version of the client libraries are you using?

Comment: firebase-admin@9.1.1, firebase-functions@3.11.0, firebase-tools@8.10.0